# Match function fails to find an existing match

Tags: r, match

I have a vector of dates (with time included) and am trying to use the `match` function (actually `%in%`) to see if another date in included in the vector. Even when I know for a fact that the date that I want to search is in the vector, `%in%` fails to find it. For example, consider the following lengthy vector of datetimes, and the date I want to search.

```
BEGIN <- strptime(paste("7/10/2018","05:22"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
END <- strptime(paste("9/3/2018","23:59:59"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
SEQ <- as.POSIXlt(seq(BEGIN,END,3600))
DATE <- strptime("8/16/2018 14:22:00","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I definitely know that `DATE` is in the vector `SEQ`, but `match` fails to find it.

```
DATE==SEQ[898]
DATE %in% SEQ
match(DATE,SEQ)
```

When I search over a specific subset of `SEQ`, it succeeds, but it fails over another nearly identical subset.

```
DATE %in% SEQ[888:900]
DATE %in% SEQ[888:length(SEQ)]
DATE %in% SEQ[887:900]
DATE %in% SEQ[887:length(SEQ)]

SEQ2 <- SEQ[888:900]
DATE %in% SEQ2
SEQ2 <- SEQ[887:900]
DATE %in% SEQ2
```

There is nothing special (that I can tell) about that 887th value, but including anything before the 888th value causes `match` to fail. I can get around this by using `which`, something like

```
ifelse(length(which(SEQ==DATE)>0),TRUE,FALSE)
```

but I am really puzzled about why `match` fails to find a match that clearly is present.

Can anyone shed light about what is going on and whether there is just something weird with my example?

Thanks.

Comment: `POSIXt` (whether `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`) are *continuous* in nature, meaning this might be due to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: I get `match(DATE,SEQ)
[1] 898`, and `DATE %in% SEQ
[1] TRUE`  so it seems your OS might be behaving differently than mine (macOS/R 3.5.2) It's also unclear why you are getting a different match location.

Comment: @r2evans That may be part of the issue. When I convert everything to character it all works. But I still seems odd that it works when `SEQ` is subsetted one way but not another. @42 There might be a platform issue. I have Windows 10, R 3.5.0, and for institutional reasons can't upgrade R right now. But I'll check a different platform when I get home tonight, and I'll report back.

Comment: There are a couple of things to realize: (1) representation of an object on the console is different than the internal storage of it, take for example `pi` which has many more digits that you are likely seeing on your console. When you convert to `character`, it honors your settings for `options("digits.secs")` so loses precision in the coersion. (2) As with all things related to R FAQ 7.31 (and floating point in general), it is likely necessary to test for "closeness" *with tolerance*, as in `abs(x - y) < 1e-9`.

Comment: @r2evans SOrry it took me awhile to get back to this. the fact that `DATE==SEQ[898]` produced `TRUE` suggests to me that it shouldn't be a tolerance issue, and that the values I was trying to match were in fact identical. But I might be misunderstanding how R represents values in different situations. In any case, updating R made the problem go away.

Comment: The fact that it worked once unfortunately does not prove that it is never a tolerance issue. I'm not debating this: the R FAQ 7.31 is a known and avoidable limitation of floating point arithmetic in digital processors (not just win/mac/linux, not just R/python, not just intel/amd/arm). Often things are "good enough" so that you do not see it, but it is there. I'm glad the upgrade worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point.  I actually went a different route anyway, because in my context it made more sense to search for values between 2 thresholds. And in that case, it makes the tolerance issue moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. This is on Windows 10, R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth", 64-bit.

```r
BEGIN <- strptime(paste("7/10/2018","05:22"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
END <- strptime(paste("9/3/2018","23:59:59"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
SEQ <- as.POSIXlt(seq(BEGIN,END,3600))
DATE <- strptime("8/16/2018 14:22:00","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

DATE %in% SEQ
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I tested this on Win 7, R 3.5.1, and it failed. Updating to R 3.6.0 seemed to fix it. I also tested on Linux Mint 18.3, R 3.4.4, and it failed, but updating R again fixed the issue.